# How can I sent email once when user was disabled in AD (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, csv, email, active-directory, smtp

I want to improve the script that automatically blocks users via TaskScheduler. I added an email sending function but I want to loop it once and I don't know how to implement something like that. Can you help me a little with this?

My code:

```
#Importowanie obecnej daty do zmiennej b

$b = (Get-Date).ToString('M"/"d"/"yyyy')

$groups = 'PLKAT-G-ORG-NON Block Users'

$groupClient1 = 'PLKAT-G-ORG-Client1 Block Users Only'





#Function to Send Email Message

function sendMail($Message) {

            
            #SMTP server name
            $SmtpServer = "mailserver"

            #Creating a mail Object
            $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
             
            #Credential
            $username = "mailserver"
            $password = "*************" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
             
            $emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)

            #Add Attachment
            #$Attachments = "attached file"
             
             
             
            #Creating SMTP server object
            $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
            $smtp.Port = 587
            $smtp.EnableSsl = $true
            $smtp.Credentials = $emailCredential

            #Email structure
            $msg.From = "my@domain.com"
            $msg.To.add("domain@my.com")
            $msg.CC.Add("do@my.com")
            #$msg.CC.Add("user3@domain.com")
            $msg.subject = "***TEST***"
            $msg.body = $Message
            #$msg.Attachments.Add($Attachments)

         #Sending email
         $smtp.Send($msg)

         "Email Sent"

};

#################### Client1 ############################

Import-Csv "I:\Clients\Client1\Block Accounts\Accounts Deactivation Test.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    
    $SamAccountName = $_."SamAccountName"     
    
    $dateDisable = $_."dateDisable"

    $dateEnable = $_."dateEnable"

    
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        If ($members -contains $SamAccountName ) {
        
           $Message = " $SamAccountName  is a member of NON Block User Group" 

           sendMail $Message
            
            }

       foreach ($group in $groupClient1) { 
       
       $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName       
       
        if ($members -contains $SamAccountName){

            $dateDisable -eq $b

             Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName | Disable-ADAccount

             $Message = "Account:  $SamAccountName was disabled"
```

#I want to send email once when user account is disabled by script, but script run every hour

```
            for($i=1; $i -eq 1; $i++) { 

             if($i -eq 1){

             sendMail $Message 
             
             }
             
       
        }
        
     }
 

    $dateEnable = $_."dateEnable"
     
     if ( $dateEnable -eq $b) {
        
        Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
        
        Write-Host "-User "$SamAccountName" Enable"
    }

   }
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is `$groupZLND` defined? What is the meaning of `for($i=1; $i -eq 1; $i++)` ? Why not simply check if the user was already disabled first? (and then do not send the mail again?)

Comment: BTW. I see you are in the habit of asking a question, getting an answer and then copy that answer with minor changes (requirements you did **not** ask for) as an answer of your own..

Comment: Okey, but my problem is if the script run every hour and check if that user was block then mail will be sent when script running. How can I implement some method if mail was sent  don't sent mail again to the date when user will be enable ?

Comment: Very simple.. just do a check to see if the user is already disabled and only proceed if that is not the case. Now you disable and send an email when needed or not.

Comment: How can I do it, I don't have any ideas :/

Comment: ... I just told you how didn't I ?

Comment: I know what you mean but I don't know how I could implement this :D


if($SamAccountName | Select-Object Enabled)

              {
             
                $Message = "Account:  $SamAccountName was disabled" 
              
                sendMail $Message

              }

Comment: Just do `$theUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName; if ($theUser.Enabled) { $theUser | Disable-ADAccount; sendMail "Account:  $SamAccountName was disabled" }` Now, if the user was already disabled, you do nothing, otherwise you disable the user and send the email.

Comment: Thank you very much, how can I implement this same function for this

if ( $dateEnable -eq $b) {
        
        Get-ADUser -Identity $SamAccountName | Enable-ADAccount
        
        Write-Host "-User "$SamAccountName" Enable"

Comment: Exactly the same way, only change to `if (-not $theUser.Enabled)`

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome, I tried different method but not this  : `if (-not $theUser.Enabled)`